# Infinitude of primes which are inert in one extension and completely split in other for extensions of prime degree.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

I want to prove the following:

> Let $L_1, \cdots , L_n$ be extensions of number field $K$ of prime degree $p$ such that each $L_i$ is disjoint from the compositum of $L_j$s for $ j\neq i $. Then there are infinitely many primes of $K$ that are inert in $L_1$ and split completely in $L_i$ for $i \geq 2 $.

I need to prove this to prove the second inequality of Global Class Field Theory (so I do not want to use the Chebotarev density theorem because that can give me the second inequality directly instead).

I have a couple of facts, consequences of the first inequality, at my disposal, which I think might be useful here.

> 1. In a non-trivial finite abelian extension of $K$, infinitely many primes of $K$ do not split completely.
> 2. In a cyclic prime power degree extension of $K$, infinitely many primes remain inert.

I first try to prove the theorem in the case where we just have $L_1$ and $L_2$, hoping that the proof will generalize easily.

In $L_1L_2$ there are infinitely many primes which do not split completely. There are infinitely many of these for which the prime lying below in $L_1$ is inert, let $S$ be set of such primes. We should show that infinitely many of primes $S$ when contracted to $L_2$ are completely split. I am stuck here.

Comment: That’s probably a very stupid question, but I’m assuming you don’t require the $L_i/K$ to be Galois?

Answer (score 3):

Right... I’m not entirely sure how to generalize this (and I’m not 100 percent sure it works), but in the case $n=2,L_i/K$ Galois, so that $L_1L_2$ is the tensor product and is Galois of group $\mathbb{F}_p^2$ (it’s of order $p^2$ and consider its subgroups).

Let $\mathfrak{q}$ be a prime of $L_2$ (above $\mathfrak{p}$ of $K$) which is inert in $L_1L_2$. There are infinitely many such $\mathfrak{p}$ that are unramified in $L_1L_2$.

Assume $\mathfrak{p}$ inert in $L_2$, then $f_{L_1L_2/K,\mathfrak{p}}=p^2$ by multiplicativity. It implies in particular that $\mathfrak{p}$ is inert in $L_1$. But then $L_1 \otimes K_{\mathfrak{p}}=L_2\otimes K_{\mathfrak{p}}$ (they’re unramified of same degree over $K_{\mathfrak{p}}$ – because Galois and prime) so $L_1L_2$ splits, a contradiction.

So such a $\mathfrak{p}$ splits in $L_2$. Assume that it splits in $L_1$, too. Then $(L_1L_2) \otimes K_{\mathfrak{p}}=L_1 \otimes (L_2 \otimes K_{\mathfrak{p}} \cong L_1 \otimes K_{\mathfrak{p}}^p=(L_1 \otimes K_{\mathfrak{p}})^p=K_{\mathfrak{p}}^{p^2}$ thus $\mathfrak{p}$ splits totally in $L_1L_2$, a contradiction.

So the primes $\mathfrak{p}$ of $K$ unramified in $L_1L_2$ such that there are primes $\mathfrak{q}$ of $L_2$ above them that are inert in $L_1L_2$ are infinitely many solutions to your question.

I think a similar argument (with $L_2\ldots L_n$ instead of $L_2$) works in general if each $L_i/K$ is Galois (with some minor adaptations) but I’m not sure.

Comment: With each $L_j/K$ cyclic of same prime degree $p$ and $E = \prod_j L_j, F= \prod_{j\ne 1} L_j$,

For $\mathfrak{p}\in K$ unramified. The Galois group is $p$-torsion so $f(E/K,\mathfrak{p})$ is either $p$ or $1$.

If $\mathfrak{q}\in F$ above $\mathfrak{p}$ is inert in $E$ then $f(E/F,\mathfrak{q})=p$ so $f(E/K,\mathfrak{p})=p$ thus $f(F/K,\mathfrak{p})=1$ ie. $\mathfrak{p}$ splits completely in $F$ thus in every $L_j,j\ne 1$. And it can't split completely in $L_1$ since otherwise we'd have $f(E/K,\mathfrak{p})=1$, so it is inert in $L_1$.

Comment: @reuns: Nice shortcut, using the $p$-torsion Galois group to show that the $f$ are always either $p$ or $1$. I was thinking of another argument (with a lot of tensor products) but it was definitely more tedious. I'm not 100 percent sure how you deduce that $f_{E/K}$ is one if each $f_{L_i/K}$ is one (at an unramified prime $\mathfrak{p}$), the argument I'm thinking of involves many tensor products (show that $E \otimes K_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is $p^n$ copies of $K_{\mathfrak{p}}$) but perhaps you know of a similar shortcut?

Comment: I'm thinking to $v$-adic extensions ($v$ a discrete valuation above $\mathfrak{p}$ extended to $E$) then $[(L_j)_v:K_v] = f(L_j/K,v)e(L_j/K,v)$, if each $f(L_j/K,v)=e(L_j/K,v)=1$ then $(\prod_j L_j)_v = K_v$ so $f(\prod_j L_j/K,v)=e(\prod_j L_j/K,v)=1$. Then Galoisness means that the $e,f$ are the same for all discrete valuation above $\mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: So completion commutes with "product" of fields? Yes, it makes sense...

Comment: Yes I'd say $(AB)_v$ contains $A_v$ and $B_v$ thus it contains $A_v B_v$, and $A_v B_v$ is complete and it contains $AB$ thus it contains $(AB)_v$.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't follow why  $L_1 \otimes K_{\mathfrak p} = L_2 \otimes K_{\mathfrak p}$ and how then $L_1L_2$ is split.

Comment: If $\mathfrak{p}$ inert in $L_1$ and $L_2$, $L_1 \otimes K_{\mathfrak{p}}$ and $L_2 \otimes K_{\mathfrak{p}}$ are unramified extensions of degree $p$ of $K_{\mathfrak{p}}$ so they’re isomorphic. Then $(L_1L_2) \otimes K_{\mathfrak{p}}=(L_1 \otimes L_2) \otimes K_{\mathfrak{p}})=L_1 \otimes (L_2 \otimes K_{\mathfrak{p}}=L_1 \otimes (L_1 \otimes K_{\mathfrak{p}})=(L_1 \otimes L_1) \otimes K_{\mathfrak{p}}=L_1^{\oplus p} \otimes K_{\mathfrak{p}}=(L_1 \otimes K_{\mathfrak{p}})^{\oplus p}$, which shows $L_1L_2$ splits at $\mathfrak{p}$.